# Passing url to django to be used as variable?

Tags: django, url

So when I'm trying to pass url to django views it cuts it. For example, I have a webpage which shows statistics of downloads for users sorted by download amount. Then I want to get details about some user, for example for "Yousuke Kataoka". I press the link and go to user page. Url should be and is mysite.com/user/Yousuke Kataoka, but in the webpage I see "Details for Yousuke", it kinda cuts the url. So of course I can't get any details, because the username is cut.

Here is part of urls.py:

```
(r'^user/(?P<username>[*_a-zA-Z0-9./-=]+)', 'dq2.web.usermon.views.user')
```

And here is user.html template:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Detailed information for {{usr}}</title>
<script src="/dq2/media/js/sorttable.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Detailed information for {{usr}}</p>
<table width="30%">
<tr><td>File Downloads (1HR)</td><td align="right">{{file_events_1h}}</td></tr>
<tr><td>File Downloads (24HR)</td><td align="right">{{file_events}}</td></tr>
<tr><td>File Downloads (7D)</td><td align="right">{{file_events_7d}}</td></tr>
<tr><td>File Downloads (30D)</td><td align="right">{{file_events_30d}}</td></tr>
<tr><td>Operations (1HR)</td><td align="right">{{op_events_1h}}</td></tr>
<tr><td>Operations (24HR)</td><td align="right">{{op_events}}</td></tr>
<tr><td>Operations (7D)</td><td align="right">{{op_events_7d}}</td></tr>
<tr><td>Operations (30D)</td><td align="right">{{op_events_30d}}</td></tr>
</table>
```

And so on..

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a space in your regex. And are you sure you meant to have `/-=` in there?

Comment: Well to be honest yes, becuase in some usernames they have /, -, =... So I should just add space? Let me try..

Comment: `/-=` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: sorry for my mistake. could you explain?

Comment: ["Ranges of characters can be indicated by giving two characters and separating them by a '-'"](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)